# Relative interior of convex sets

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

It is known that whenever a set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex then $\text{cl}(\text{ri}\hspace{0.1cm} C)=\text{cl}\hspace{0.1cm} C$ and $\text{ri}(\text{cl}\hspace{0.1cm}C)=\text{ri}\hspace{0.1cm}C$ where $\text{cl}\hspace{0.1cm}C$ and $\text{ri}\hspace{0.1cm}C$ are the closure and the relative interior of a set $C$. Why wouldn't this statement hold in general? What are counterexamples when $C$ is not convex?

Comment: There is not problem defining the relative interior. The only thing is that the relative interior is empty. In fact, the affine hull of the circle is the whole plane. Therefore the intersections of balls and the affine hull are just the same balls. For a point on the circle to be in the relative interior a ball around it would have to be contained in the circle. Since this never happens, the relative interior is empty. Therefore, $cl(ri(C))=cl(\emptyset)=\emptyset\neq C$.

Comment: To get an example for the other equation, look at $C$ a punctured open disc in the plane. Then $ri(C)=C$. But $ri(cl(C))=ri(\text{ the open whole disc})=\text{the whole open disc}$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider a sphere $C$ (without interior) in $\mathbb{R}^2$. How would you sensibly define "relative interior"? The set $C$ should serve as a counterexample.

Comment: I think you can define a relative interior for the circle from the induced topology on it from the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. No?

Comment: @Arian There is not problem defining the relative interior. The only thing is that the relative interior is empty. In fact, the affine hull of the circle is the whole plane. Therefore the intersections of balls and the affine hull are just the same balls. For a point on the circle to be in the relative interior a ball around it would have to be contained in the circle. Since this never happens, the relative interior is empty. Therefore, $cl(ri(C))=cl(\emptyset)=\emptyset\neq C$

Comment: @Aolov Yes, so the usual definition will not give you much. If anything, we would want the relative interior to be $C$ itself...

Comment: @max_zorn The usual definition is perfectly applicable, since relative interior applies to any set, not only convex.

Comment: @AOlov yes, but Arian wanted nonempty relative interior so this is not working well in this case...

Comment: @max_zorn 'this is not working well in this case'. What is not working well? You need to go read the definition such that you understand why the example you gave is an example. You sound confused.

Comment: @AOlov: It is not working well (in fact not at all) because the relative interior of $C$ is empty contrary what was desirable in the original post. What would be cool is to come up with a relative interior that is the same for convex sets but would give $C$ in my example. Any ideas from you?

Comment: @max_zorn You seem to be confused. One doesn't come up with a relative interior. [Its definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_interior) is given and works for all sets. The circle happens to have empty relative interior, other sets (even non-convex ones like the punctured disc) have non-empty relative interior.

Comment: @AOlov I am not confused, you don't get the point. It is useless because it can be empty. What would be nice is to have a variant of the relative interior that (i) is the same for convex sets and (ii) would give us $C$ and not the empty set for $C$ above. The classical relative interior cannot do this...

Comment: Your point is non-sense. You can always define such a function of sets.